# App crashes when select Release mode but in debug mode works perfectly

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, proguard

I want to reduce size of my application therefore I am using `minifyEnabled true` in release mode but due to this application crashes. Following is my

> build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // replace with the current version of the Android plugin
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        // the latest version of the android-apt plugin
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

    apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId
     }
     }

     android {
     compileSdkVersion 21
     buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

     defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iifl.news.codereduce"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.0.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.+'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.+'
    apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'


    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.0.0'

    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
   }
```

I had added proguard-rules.pro.  If I remove this then it gives me multiple warning.

```
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp.**


-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-dontwarn retrofit.**

-keep class okio.** { *; }
-dontwarn okio.**

-keep class dagger.** { *; }
-dontwarn dagger.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn    com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.JavaApiConverter$CacheHttpURLConnection
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl
```

My Manifest is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.iifl.news.codereduce" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<application
    android:name=".app.IIFLApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.BaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_iiflbase"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My IIFLApplication class is like:

```
    public class IIFLApplication extends Application {

    private ObjectGraph applicationGraph;
    private Tracker tracker;

    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-61984632-2";

    public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, GLOBAL_TRACKER, ECOMMERCE_TRACKER,
    }

    public HashMap mTrackers = new HashMap();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        /*if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(new DebugTree());
        } else {
            //Timber.plant(new CrashlyticsTree());
        }*/

        //create object graph
        applicationGraph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());
        applicationGraph.inject(this);
    }

    private List<Object> getModules() {
        return Arrays.<Object>asList(new AppModule(this));
    }

    public ObjectGraph getApplicationGraph() {
        return this.applicationGraph;
    }

    /**
     * A tree which logs important information for crash reporting.
     */
    private static class CrashlyticsTree extends Timber.HollowTree {
        @Override
        public void v(String message, Object... args) {
            logMessage(message, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void v(Throwable t, String message, Object... args) {
            logMessage(message, args);
            // NOTE: We are explicitly not sending the exception to Crashlytics here.
        }

        @Override
        public void i(String message, Object... args) {
            logMessage(message, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void i(Throwable t, String message, Object... args) {
            logMessage(message, args);
            // NOTE: We are explicitly not sending the exception to Crashlytics here.
        }

        @Override
        public void w(String message, Object... args) {
            logMessage("WARN: " + message, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void w(Throwable t, String message, Object... args) {
            logMessage("WARN: " + message, args);
            // NOTE: We are explicitly not sending the exception to Crashlytics here.
        }

        @Override
        public void e(String message, Object... args) {
            logMessage("ERROR: " + message, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void e(Throwable t, String message, Object... args) {
            logMessage("ERROR: " + message, args);
            //Crashlytics.logException(t);
        }

        private void logMessage(String message, Object... args) {
            //Crashlytics.log(String.format(message, args));
        }
    }



    public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName appTracker) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(appTracker)) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (appTracker == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID) : (appTracker == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker) : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(appTracker, t);
        }
        return (Tracker) mTrackers.get(appTracker);
    }
   }
```

I think is due to proguard. But I am not getting what wrong I am doing. Any suugestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Folllowing is my logcat: Application crashesh instantly after run.

```
05-22 15:15:43.067    3158-3158/com.iifl.news.codereduce E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.iifl.news.codereduce, PID: 3158
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.iifl.news.codereduce.app.IIFLApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class com.iifl.news.codereduce.a.b could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4521)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class com.iifl.news.codereduce.a.b could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.
        at dagger.internal.FailoverLoader$1.create(Unknown Source)
        at dagger.internal.FailoverLoader$1.create(Unknown Source)
        at dagger.internal.Memoizer.get(Unknown Source)
        at dagger.internal.FailoverLoader.getModuleAdapter(Unknown Source)
        at dagger.internal.Modules.loadModules(Unknown Source)
        at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.makeGraph(Unknown Source)
        at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at dagger.ObjectGraph.create(Unknown Source)
        at com.iifl.news.codereduce.app.IIFLApplication.onCreate(Unknown    Source)
        at     android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
            at
```

I had also tried using `-keep class com.iifl.news.codereduce.{ *; }
-dontwarn com.iifl.news.codereduce.**`  But still in release mode it crash and in debug mode runs well.

I had also tried adding `androidTestApt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'` in dependencies. But No luck

Comment: @HarshDattani  logcat has been added

Comment: can you look in your mapping.txt file and find what `com.iifl.news.codereduce.a.b` is supposed to be and add the code for that obfuscated class to your question? (if its not AppModule)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. The problem was proguard is removing unused class methods when the app launches, but the app may need those class methods later down on the way for example when you switching to other activity or exiting the app, and that was when the app crashed. You need to change minifyEnabled attribute to false to keep unused methods permanently. But still you can shrink all the files during release using a shrink attribute. Shrinking may boost app's performance.

```
    release {
        minifyEnabled false //keeps unused methods instead of removing them
        shrinkResources true //to shrink files
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

Comment: I added `shrinkResources true` and got this gradle build error: Removing unused resources requires unused code shrinking to be turned on. See http://d.android.com/r/tools/shrink-resources.html for more information.

Comment: This is the wrong answer, if suppose I have to enable proguard and wanted to secure my code then what should I do? Because app get crashed when enabling proguard in release version, whereas in debud it works fine.

Comment: Dissabling necessary things (minifyEnabled) to make things worse is almost never a good solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Retrofit` I assume you will have classes that you will use as POJOs to convert to from JSON. (i.e. The Java objects you get created when Retrofit returns a response)

These classes should **not** be obfuscated by proguard and you will need to remove them as follows (putting them inside a single package will help!):

```
-keep class com.app.example.{ *; }
-dontwarn com.app.example.**
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I had done what you suggest still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion. I am still stuck into this. Google lots but not getting hint.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1`  from `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I also tried what you suggest but still same error. Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on *why* this should help.